# how to create a load older or load more call with mongoose

Tags: mongoose

You may flag it as duplicated question but I don't know how to say what I wan't to do so it's hard to search for answers.

If I have a model like

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var messageSchema = new Schema({
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    sender: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId},
    content: String
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Message', messageSchema);
```

so there will be many messages registered after a while.

Now i display them but only 10 in a row.

```
var Message = require('../models/message');
Message.find().sort('-created_at').limit(10).exec(function(err, messages) {
    var last = messages[messages.length - 1]._id
});
```

I placed a button 'Load older' that is supposed to bring the previous 10 messages starting from 'last' but I don't know how to do.

Have an idea of the way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong from the very start. I thought using the _id of the last document found would be the solution but the property "created_at" was actually the key.

Loading older messages comes easy when doing so

```
var last = new Date(messages[messages.length - 1].created_at);
Message.find().where('created_at').lt(last).exec()
```

since 'created_at' is registered as date type, such query is possible.